# SQL WHERE clause to pick data for last 7 days

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to build a view on the server with a SELECT statement and pick all records that are created at the last 7 days?

Original `creation_date` field is in `varchar` like `'18/11/08'` and I use the `CONVERT(datetime, creation_date,11)` to convert it into `2018-11-08 00:00:00.000`, but I don't know how to do in the `WHERE` clause, so it only selects all records created for last 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use where clause like below

```
 select t.* from your_table t
 where CONVERT(datetime, creation_date,11)>= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the best performance, you should keep the calculation away from the column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <YourTable>
WHERE creation_date >= CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()), 11)
```

This will handle it well because of the format of the varchar - yy/mm/dd. Would not have worked with all formats

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is store dates properly to begin with - in a column with a `Date` data type.
Assuming you can't change the database structure, you can use `DateDiff` with `GetDate()`:

```
SELECT <ColumnsList>
FROM <TableName>
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(datetime, creation_date,11), GETDATE()) <= 7
```

Of course, you need to replace the `<ColumnsList>` with the list of columns and `<TableName>` with the actual table name.

Comment: Making a calculation on a column like this can cause horrible performance

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I agree, and so is keeping the date column as varchar (not to mention all the other potential problems)

Comment: no, converting the whole table to a different datatype in order to compare is never faster than comparing varchar itself, Yes there can be problems with invalid data. But that will be an issue for all answers. Your will give an error, mine will compare with a potential wrong result - if you can call it wrong with invalid data

Comment: I'm not talking about converting the whole table every time you query, I'm talking about refactoring that once and keeping the Date in a `Date` data type. After that, it's best to use `dateColumn >= DateAdd(Day, -7 GetDate())`

Comment: yes, having the correct datatype would be the prefered solution. But that is not always possible, because existing code often require the current format

Comment: That's why I started my answer with "The best thing to do is..." I went with the DateDiff on the column because I already had the `convert` from the question. Assuming the column type can't change, your code is better than mine.